# What is the costs of querying on subdocuments in cosmosdb?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What is the costs of querying on subdocuments in cosmosdb ? When reading the documentation it seems that only IDs and their paths are indexed.

Does it means that each time you are [querying on a subdocuments](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#FromClause) using the `From` clause like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Families.children
```

it will parse the documents matching this path and create a view of them? Are sub documents stored as well?

Comment: Not sure where you saw that, but... All properties are indexed, including subdocument properties. There's no parsing taking place for a query to search subdocuments. As for costs, you can measure the query by looking at the Request Unit charge returned in the header. It's also shown to you if you run your query via the portal.

Comment: What do you mean by all propertis are indexedd? The full json path ( ex /locations/0/country/france)  will be associated to the id of the doc according to the following doc and papers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies
 http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p1668-shukla.pdf . But does it also directly store the content of the subdocuments  to use them during queries when we filter with FROM? I’m curious how efficient is a query over them.

Comment: in other words are subdocuments stored during indexing or just their paths?

Answer (score 1):

#### How indexing works

CosmosDB stores the entire JSON document as a tree (any depth, including what i guess you call "subdocuments"). The `FROM..IN` join syntax is just a syntactic sugar to make it easier for you to express those paths in your SQL query. For example, "remove" array indexes from tree paths and provide pretty shortcuts for both `SELECT` and `WHERE` part. It never actually includes more data to your query just assigns named pointers to parts within each of the to-be-returned root documents.

The indexed paths just contain the reference to matching document roots they do not make copies of the "subdocuments". Contrary to relational SQL, there is no covering index in CosmosDB.

When you "select a subdocument" you are actually instructing cosmosDB to return a  projection from root document tree-presentation to its subpart. In a sense it is (non-serialized) view to the original document.

**Definitely go and check the video [Azure Cosmos DB Indexing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-cosmosdb-indexing/) which explains it really well.** The main takeaway is this image (screenshot from the above video):
[image]

#### Regarding performance

Most important for performance is not HOW you reference an node in index tree, but whether it is indexed at all and selective enough. Where the index value resides in document is in practice not too relevant.

I guess there is a theoretical overhead to traversing the index tree (and document tree) deeper but i'm pretty sure the impact is in practice so micro you usually can't even measure it. Most of the work in that N ms query is spent elsewhere (checking additional predicates on matching documents from index, building output Json object from internal tree model, serialization).

Similarly to relational SQL, returning only "subdocuments" is most likely slightly faster compared to full root documents, because the SELECT-step can skip non-relevant parts of the document tree. But probably it depends more on overall included tree node count and data size, and not as much on the shape of the tree.

.. and the usual advice on perfomance - **DO write some tests**. For CosmosDB you can measure the RU cost and check the [PopulateQueryMetrics header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics).

#### UPDATE: Are subdocuments stored?

The above graphics would suggest that they are not - linking to root document only. But it is obviously a simplification and hence not conclusive. Still, you should be able to design a test for this. Alternative is to go ask the team for internal design via askcosmosdb@microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks. But the paper I linked give the same information. But this is the last step I am missing: how the form get the extracted values on the path given. Is it store somewhere as a fragment (the paper suggests there are some fragments IDs) or does it always traverse the docs corresponding to the index to return the values?

Comment: Ah, I misread your question focus. Not really answering your question here, though it could be useful information to some other readers + suggestion to test it out is still valid. If you want to know the details of internal design and implementation you should probably ask the cosmosDB team directly.